# Генерация ключа для защиты от curl

Tags: php, mysql, curl

Я, конечно, понимаю, что curl - это вообще законная вещь. Но в один прекрасный момент какой-то пользователь сайта сделал цикл, который отправляет "123" в бд бесконечно. Он написал, что с помощью curl. Каким образом можно сделать ключ, чтобы он генерировался в `<input type="hidden" value="код"` и подтверждался на странице публикации? Возможно, это защитит.

Comment: Нет, не защитит. Пока может браузер, может и curl.

Comment: @D-side, а стоит ли это делать? И как вообще защититься?

Comment: Для начала можно воткнуть CSRF-токен https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B6%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0

Comment: @Lexx918, можно пример?)

Comment: Лучше подойти логически. Пользователь отправляет бесконечно текст "123" - в чем именно здесь проблема, которую надо решить? Что пользователь не должен публиковать короткий текст? Или не должен делать это слишком часто? Или он может публиковать не более 1 статьи в день/час/минуту? Решайте задачу в общем виде прежде всего. Если вы поставите адекватные рамки, которые не будут мешать обычным пользователям, но будут затруднять балавство хулиганов - это понизит интерес безобразничать и не сильно помешает хорошим пользователям

Comment: @wirtwelt, циклически отправляет через curl текст "123" в бд

Comment: Глядя на логи к серверу можно сделать вывод что сервер регулярно кто-то пытается ломать, присылают и попытки инжекции sql, и попытки инжекции js и ещё кучу хлама. То что 123 присылают - это ещё цветочки.

Comment: @NIKOLAY, я понял это из вопроса. Мой комментарий относится к вам - `что именно в действиях пользователя не правильно?` Вы его себе сами задайте, разложите на кусочки, и ограничивайте конкретно те моменты, которые не правильны. Например я общаюсь в чате со своей женой и шлю ей каждую секунду сообщение с текстом `123`. Что в этом плохого? Что хочу то и шлю, моя переписка. А вот если клиент на сайте оформляет заказ и отсылает в контактах `123` вместо телефона - нужна проверка формата уже. Обычно при частых операциях сайты просто просят ввести капчу - тот же Google при частом поиске. Вот и все

Comment: Надо отрубать не curl, надо отрубать возможность мусорить в БД, способ замусоривания не принципиален.